# Import Team Project Set in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I import a team project set in Eclipse programmatically without using the wizard? 
I would like to do it programmatically in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at the code for the class that implements the wizard, `org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.wizards.ProjectSetImportWizard` to see what it does. Specifically, look at the `doFinish()` method. There is an "operation" class that does most of the work, so you just have to create one correctly and then `run()` it.